# dynamic stack with static array C

Tags: c

I have been doing excercises from a book. And I am stuck on the meaning of this qustion. Assuming that you store integer values on the stac and that using a static array to store data provide a createStack() deleteStack(stack) methods.

My interpretation is

```
typedef struct {
  int values;
  char data[50];

} StackData;

typedef struct n {
  StackData d; // store some data in node
  struct n *successor; // store successor of node
  // as typedef is not yet completed
  // name StackNode cannot be used
} SatckNode;


typedef struct {
  StackNode *head;
  StackNode *current;
} Stacklist;
```

I know these arent the methods. But i want to know if I am going about it the right way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a static array for the values, then you don't technically need `createStack()` and `deleteStack()` functions, because you can just create a `struct stack` or whatever on the stack (pun intended) and you're done.

If you do want to, though, (and you might legitimately want to, e.g. to avoid having to explicitly initialize `top`, or to hide the implementation behind an opaque type, or to be able to return one from a function without copying a potentially large array) this'll do it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define STACKSIZE 50

typedef struct stack * Stack;

struct stack {
    size_t top;
    int values[STACKSIZE];
};

Stack createStack(void)
{
    Stack new_stack = malloc(sizeof *new_stack);
    if ( !new_stack ) {
        perror("couldn't allocate memory");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    new_stack->top = 0;
    return new_stack;
}

void deleteStack(Stack stack)
{
    free(stack);
}

void push(Stack stack, const int n)
{
    if ( stack->top < STACKSIZE ) {
        stack->values[stack->top++] = n;
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Stack full - exiting.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

int pop(Stack stack)
{
    if ( stack->top > 0 ) {
        return stack->values[--stack->top];
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Stack empty - exiting.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    Stack mystack = createStack();

    push(mystack, 3);
    push(mystack, 1);
    push(mystack, 4);
    push(mystack, 1);
    push(mystack, 5);

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i ) {
        printf("Popped %d from stack.\n", pop(mystack));
    }

    deleteStack(mystack);

    return 0;
}
```

Right now you seem to want a stack with values in a static array, but then you start defining structs for nodes and lists, as if you want a linked list implementation. The two implementations are obviously pretty different.

Comment: Just one question. Why do you return new_Stack, is it possible to implement this using void and having no return type?

Comment: No, you cannot return anything if a function has no return type. You'd have to create a pointer and then pass its address into the `createStack()` function, which is possible, but needlessly complicated given the alternative above.

Comment: Perfect, I have a much better understanding of stacks now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right way - just a couple of comments.

In `Stacklist`, I don't get why you have pointers to two of the nodes in the stack.
Usually, stacks only keep a reference to the item on the top of the stack.
In addition, they either keep a counter of how big is the stack, or a pointer to the node on the bottom of the stack (which is what you probably mean by `head`, and reference the head node by `current`?).

And don't forget to initialize everything whenever you create any of those structures :P usually ends up in endless hours of headache.

Keep up the good work.